# How to know Event emitted value has been changed in Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable

I am developing an Angular 4 application. I have a search component, where the user inputs a string. Whenever the user enters a value and submits it, I am emitting the value from the `SearchComponent` to `DisplayComponent`.

Emitting value in SearchComponent

```
@Output() userInput: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
onFormSubmit() {
    this.userInput.emit(this.searchForm.value.SearchInputValue);
}
```

DisplayComponent HTML looks like

```
<app-search (userInput)="valueFromSearch"></app-search>
<div class="some-other-html></div>
```

DisplayComponent TS file looks like

```
valueFromSearch: string;
constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}
ngOnInit() {
    this.someService.getSomeData(valueFromSearch)
       .subscribe((data) => {console.log("Success! data is ",data)},
       (error) => {console.log("Something went wrong", error)})
}
```

But how to run the `someService` function whenever, the `valueFromSearch` changes? Should I use BehaviorSubject to keep listening for the changes in `valueFromSearch`?

Is there any function to know that the value has changed? Please help me resolve this.

Comment: (change) method on input

Comment: @porgo The value from search input is being emitted, but how do I know the value changed in the DisplayComponent?

Answer (score 0):

you can make valueFromSearch() a method which will invoke everytime you emit from search

> DisplayComponent HTML

```
<app-search (userInput)="valueFromSearch(value)"></app-search>
<div class="some-other-html></div>
```

> DisplayComponent TS file

```
constructor(private someService: SomeService) {}
valueFromSearch(value: string) {
    this.someService.getSomeData(value)
       .subscribe((data) => {console.log("Success! data is ",data)},
       (error) => {console.log("Something went wrong", error)})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    let data = changes.valueFromSearch.currentValue;
    // This only work with a change not if it has the same value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if @JayDeeEss's method will work right away but a slight modification to it definitely seems workable.

Like his suggestion, make `valueFromSearch` a **method** (remove this declaration: `valueFromSearch: string;` from your component) that gets invoked every time the `userInput` `EventEmitter` emits a new value.

> DisplayComponent HTML (notice the change in the argument passed to `valueFromSearch()`; from `(value)` to `($event)` )

```
<app-search (userInput)="valueFromSearch($event)"></app-search>
<div class="some-other-html></div>
```

> DisplayComponent TS file (inside the component, the argument name doesn't matter)

```
valueFromSearch(value: string) {
 // handle the changed 'value' based on required logic
}
```